# yacc: What does %{} mean in yacc?

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, yacc

Does it mean just copy the C code?
This is excerpted from ruby source code parse.y

```
%{

#ifndef PARSER_DEBUG
#define PARSER_DEBUG 0
#endif
#define YYDEBUG 1
#define YYERROR_VERBOSE 1
#define YYSTACK_USE_ALLOCA 0

#include "ruby/ruby.h"
#include "ruby/st.h"
#include "ruby/encoding.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition section is to be put within the `%{` and `%}`

> The definitions section consists of token declarations and C code
>   bracketed by "%{" and "%}".

[**DOC**](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/pry1.html)